How to create embeddings which represents some object and put all together into all embeddings?
how do I create embeddings for the user database? I made text fields for users and divided them into sections, now I want to add it to the database and in the metadata I added an identifier that specifies for which candidate a given embedding belongs. Unfortunately RAG chat does not work correctly and invents data... how do I improve this logic?
in the examples I only see documents and these are simple examples, how to apply RAG to such a problem?
